# Simultaneous transitions in D3js

Tags: d3.js, transition

I have a group of objects in D3js that contains some rect objects and some text objects. I would like to make a transition on the rectangles and on the text objects at the same time. So far I have a transition on the rect objects and use an "each" call to start a function that makes transitions on the text objects. However, the transitions on the text objects execute a lot faster than on the rect objects. Ideally the text should move one box ahead as the next box is changing colors. Such that a transition on a rectangle and a text object is performed simultaneously, before the next transition is started. See the attached example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/3008/).
The code that causes me trouble is the following block:

```
var col_count = 0; // The next rectangle to color
function inc_count(d, i) {
if ( col_count < array_length - 2){
    col_count = col_count + 1;

}
d3.select("#line_id").transition().duration(1000).attr("x2", start_x + box_data[0]*i + offset*i);
d3.select("#fit_id").transition().duration(1000).attr("x", start_x + 9 + i * (box_data[0] + offset)/2);
d3.select("#pred_id").transition().duration(1000).attr("x", start_x + 7 + (i+1) *box_data[0]);

}


// Create function to control animation
box_group.selectAll("rect")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 1000;}) // sets waiting period for transitions on each element
    .each(function(d,i) { return inc_count(d,i);})
    .style("fill", function(d,i) {return colorBoxes(d,i);});
```

Comment: You have 5 rects that delay a second with a transition that takes 2 seconds. 
 That means the last rect will be done transitioning in 6 seconds.  So, just set the text to transition for 6 seonds?  [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/3012/)

Comment: Thank you for the input. It was very helpful. Alas the text is still moving fluently without stopping on the way. I would like it to stop each time it has moved one block ahead, just like the coloring of the rectangles stops temporarily before coloring the next one. Is this possible? I have tried adding a delay, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't have time for a real answer, but look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/LPbTRdUvLdMpph9TXpuj?p=preview)